# Building a hash in a conditional way

Tags: ruby, hash, conditional-statements

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.10 and I would like to build an hash key\value pairs in a conditional way. That is, I would like to add a key and its related value if a condition is matched:

```
hash = {
  :key1 => value1,
  :key2 => value2, # This key2\value2 pair should be added only 'if condition' is 'true'
  :key3 => value3,
  ...
}
```

How can I do that and keep a *"good" readability* for the code? Am I "forced" to use the `merge` method?

Comment: Where do the keys and values come from?  A different hash?

Comment: @Ray Toal - No from a different hash. I am building an hash from scratch.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.  The data has to come from somewhere: a string, another hash, an array, or someplace else.  Even if you "build the hash from scratch" you have to have the data.  Writing conditional insertions in a hash literal isn't done in Ruby; you can delete after the fact using Chris Jester-Young's technique.

Comment: is there just one condition that controls all the conditional values?

Comment: @Martin DeMello - No. One condition is used in order to add or not just *one* key\value pairs.

Comment: @backo you mean there's exactly one conditional value in the entire hash? if so i'd just say insert it at the end

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I prefer `tap`, as I think it provides a cleaner solution than the ones described here by not requiring any hacky deleting of elements and by clearly defining the scope in which the hash is being built.

It also means you don't need to declare an unnecessary local variable, which I always hate.

In case you haven't come across it before, `tap` is very simple - it's a method on `Object` that accepts a block and always returns the object it was called on. So to build up a hash conditionally you could do this:

```
Hash.new.tap do |my_hash|
  my_hash[:x] = 1 if condition_1
  my_hash[:y] = 2 if condition_2
  ...
end
```

There are many interesting uses for `tap`, this is just one.

Comment: Is the assignment missing? `hash = Hash.new.tap do ...`

Comment: It depends if you want to assign it to anything. For me, typically, this is more than enough for a method to do by itself, so this would just be the entire body of the method - no need to assign it to anything.

Comment: Is it possible to do an else condition in this as well?

Comment: @SankalpSingha Yes, but it's not as pretty: Either using ternary expression like `condition_1 ? my_hash[:x1] : my_hash[:x2]` or `if condition_1 then my_hash[:x1] else my_hash[:x2] end` or even making it multiline will work.

Answer (score 45):

A functional approach with `Hash.compact`:

```
hash = {
  :key1 => 1,
  :key2 => (2 if condition),
  :key3 => 3,
}.compact
```

Comment: This is a great answer as well.

Comment: In fact, if you are just trying to not include the keys if they don't exist (as in my case), this is cleaner.

Comment: The downside to this approach is if you need some values in your hash to be nil

Comment: If you're not on Ruby 2.4+ and are using Rails, ActiveSupport also provides `Hash#compact`.

Comment: This approach is very helpful if you're trying to build a hash of tag helper options and the `tap` approach is (more) unwieldy

Answer (score 14):

Probably best to keep it simple if you're concerned about readability:

```
hash = {}
hash[:key1] = value1
hash[:key2] = value2 if condition?
hash[:key3] = value3
...
```

Comment: I like `tap` but honestly, this is probably the way to go since it's not doing anything fancy or magical. It's the "lowest common denominator" solution.

Comment: I'm coming back to this 8 months later and unbeknownst to me, I came to the same conclusion as my past self. Less magic the better.

Answer (score 7):

Keep it simple:

```ruby
hash = {
  key1: value1,
  key3: value3,
}

hash[:key2] = value2 if condition
```

This way you also visually separate your special case, which might get unnoticed if it is buried within hash literal assignment.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. All the other answers are either over engineered and/or harder on the eyes.

Answer (score 4):

I use `merge` and the ternary  operator for that situation,

```
hash = {
  :key1 => value1,
  :key3 => value3,
  ...
}.merge(condition ? {:key2 => value2} : {})
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple as this:

```
hash = {
  :key1 => value1,
  **(condition ? {key2: value2} : {})
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

IF you build hash from some kind of Enumerable data, you can use inject, for example:

```
raw_data.inject({}){ |a,e| a[e.name] = e.value if expr; a }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to add few keys under single condition, you can use `merge`:

```
hash = {
  :key1 => value1,
  :key2 => value2,
  :key3 => value3
}

if condition
  hash.merge!(
    :key5 => value4,
    :key5 => value5,
    :key6 => value6
  )
end

hash
```

Answer (score 0):

First build your hash thusly:

```
hash = {
  :key1 => value1,
  :key2 => condition ? value2 : :delete_me,
  :key3 => value3
}
```

Then do this after building your hash:

```
hash.delete_if {|_, v| v == :delete_me}
```

Unless your hash is frozen or otherwise immutable, this would effectively only keep values that are present.

Comment: I must build an hash from scratch.

Comment: @Backo: Correct. Build your hash (with both present and blank values), then run that `delete_if` line to nuke off the blank ones.

Comment: Correct. The condition is not run on the 'value' itself but on an "external" method. I updated the question.

Comment: @Backo: Updated post accordingly.

Comment: Does not work in the case that value2's legitimate value is `:delete_me`. In that case it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Using fetch can be useful if you're populating a hash from optional attributes somewhere else. Look at this example:

```js
def create_watchable_data(attrs = {})
  return WatchableData.new({
    id:             attrs.fetch(:id, '/catalog/titles/breaking_bad_2_737'),
    titles:         attrs.fetch(:titles, ['737']),
    url:            attrs.fetch(:url, 'http://www.netflix.com/shows/breaking_bad/3423432'),
    year:           attrs.fetch(:year, '1993'),
    watchable_type: attrs.fetch(:watchable_type, 'Show'),
    season_title:   attrs.fetch(:season_title, 'Season 2'),
    show_title:     attrs.fetch(:id, 'Breaking Bad')
  })
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Same idea as Chris Jester-Young, with a slight readability trick

```
def cond(x)
  condition ? x : :delete_me
end

hash = {
  :key1 => value1,
  :key2 => cond(value2),
  :key3 => value3
}
```

and then postprocess to remove the `:delete_me` entries